# how to cache the javascript file

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

Hello I am trying make a browser cache experiment.
like this

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=Tool.GetFileRefUrl("js_cached.js")%>' ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lastFile = fun();
    </script>
    <script src="js_cached.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cacheFile = fun();
    </script>
</head><body>
<form>
<div>

    The cache file is :<script type="text/javascript">
                           document.writeln(cacheFile);
                    </script>
    <br />
    The last file is :<script type="text/javascript">
                          document.writeln(lastFile);
                    </script>    
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

`Tool.GetFileRefUrl("js_cached.js")` will return a random js file string every time like `"js_cached.js?v=8752162122311"`

The first time the `fun()` runs it returns "A", so the page will show:

> The cache file is :A
>   The last file is :A

Now I changed the file `js_cached.js` which on the web server and make `fun()` return "B" and I hope too see the result:

> The cache file is :A
>   The last file is :B

but it actually is:

> The cache file is :B
>   The last file is :B

Is something wrong? Why does the browser not cache the js file? Did I make an incorrect assumption?

the fun is

```
    function fun() {
    return "A";//after modify it be "B"
}
```

the Tool.GetFileRefUrl is

```
public class Tool
{
    public static string GetFileRefUrl(string url)
    {
        var ticks = GetLastWriteTime(url);
        var result = string.Format("{0}?v={1}", url, ticks);
        return result;
    }

    private static long GetLastWriteTime(string fileName)
    {
        var lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName));
        return lastWriteTime.Ticks;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to include the fun-function in your question because thats where your problem is...

Comment: How does your server handle the `v` parameter? Please post the whole server responses, including cache headers and content. Also, how did you reload the page?

Comment: I add the fun() and Tool.GetFileRefUrl("js_cached.js") in my question.
And I reload the page by use press F5 or copy the url to open new browser tab. 
tks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I got a way to cache the js file
add the page to your browser tab (mark link? well I'm not sure what it is in English, just like My Favorites on IE)
Open the link , your will see

```
The cache file is :A
The last file is :A
```

modify the js file,and open new tab by mark link

```
The cache file is :A
The last file is :B
```

Tks Bergi for your prompt :)